# Read One URl Parameter using php

Tags: php

I want to read one parameter from a specific URl :

Like : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrOiL74P-9E&feature=watch

Output should be : MrOiL74P-9E

I try to search and I found this function :

```
function remove_query_part($url, $term)
{
    $query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    if ($frag = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT)) {
        $frag = '#' . $frag;
    }
    parse_str($query_str, $query_arr);
    unset($query_arr[$term]);
    $new = '?' . http_build_query($query_arr) . $frag;
    return str_replace(strstr($url, '?'), $new, $url);
}
```

This function just remove one parameter and return the rest. Can anyone edit this function to return just the video ID and Ignore whatever else in the URL.

Comment: Have you tried something? Have you tried understanding how this code works? Then the answer would be pretty obvious. Think for yourself, don't expect to find every code piece on Google (or SO for that matter).

Comment: I search too hard to find the above function. I'm just new using php and can't edit it by myself.

Comment: Look up what each function in this code does in the manual: http://php.net. It's the fastest way to learn.

Comment: I will start using php.net. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query_str, $args);

print $args['v'];   // <- MrOiL74P-9E
```

I think you know how to put this into a function...

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
$url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrOiL74P-9E&feature=watch';

function test($url)
{
    $data=parse_url($url);

    if(!isset($data['query']))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        $ex=explode('&', $data['query']);

        foreach($ex as $key => $val)
        {
            $param=explode('=', $val);

            if($param[0]=='v')
            {
                return $param[1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo test($url);
```

Comment: I just apply this function into my project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good luck. Remember, that is the dirty way. Try and check the function definitions on php.net often. There's a lot to learn there!.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but you could try....

```
function remove_query_part($url, $term) { 

// get the query part of the string (i.e. after the '?')
$query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$queryItems = explode('&', $query_str); 

$item = array(); 
$itemArray = array();
foreach ($queryItems as $item) {
    $itemArray = explode('=', $item); 
if($item[0] == $term) {
    return $item[1]; 
}

} 

return false; 
}
```